# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS: How to run steam on nvidia-gl-440 or install the older libnvidia-gl-390:i386 alongside it?

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, steam

I have the nvidia driver version 440.33.01 and

```
sudo aptitude search ~i | grep -i nvidia-gl
```

shows `i A libnvidia-gl-440 - NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD` I get the error `SteamUpdate : An X Error occurred X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext` to which I found a solution on https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/0/3140616601474785172/ stating that I am missing 32-bit libraries and i need to install an older version of the driver as

```
sudo apt-get install libnvidia-gl-390:i386
```

My problem is that my CUDAtoolkit requires the 440 version. So, is there anyway I can install the 32 bit libraries or keep two nvidia drivers on my ubuntu 18.04 64-bit ? I previously tried sudo apt-get install libnvidia-gl-390:i386 but it removed some of my 440 files or maybe replaced it completely and CUDA went berserk and I had to purge everything and re-install the drivers. I tried searching "how to install multiple nvidia drivers ubuntu 18.04" but nothing showed up.

Thanks!